# Can you update setInterval variable while it runs

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I need to modify existing slider. Its slides now have differing data-seconds added to it and need be active that long. Previously I had:

```
var slidePause = 10;
function startSlideBanner() {
  bannerTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, slidePause * 1000);
}
startSlideBanner();
```

Which worked infinitely well. Now I would need to update slidePause variable every iteration. Looking for an example if its possible.

Answer (score 2):

No: You cannot do it with `setInterval`. Once it is set, it may only be cancelled.

What you can do however, is use `setTimeout` to achieve your goals. While this can be done recursively, I prefer to take advantage of promises to do it iteratively:

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
let slidePause = 10;

async function startSlideBanner() {
   while(true) {
     await wait(slidePause * 1000);
     nextSlide();
     
     // Example: Double the time for each slide
     slidePause = slidePause * 2;
   }
}

startSlideBanner();
```